# Как сделать клон коллекции?

Tags: c#, .net

Как сделать клон ObservableCollection?

Вот такой способ, я так понимаю, просто копирует ссылки?

```
    private ObservableCollection<Vm> _observable;

    public override void Execute(ObservableCollection<Vm> obs)
    {
        _observable = new ObservableCollection<Vm>(obs);
    }
```

Comment: А что именно вы хотите? Глубокое копирование, чтобы VM-объекты тоже копировались? Опишите полностью желаемый эффект.

Comment: @VladD, да, мне нужно глубокое копирование. Внутри коллекции VM с состояниями объектов, мне нужно их все подменять на другое состояние и чтобы UI на это отреагировал.

Comment: Окей, понятно. А как несчастному компилятору догадаться, как склонировать VM-объект? Откуда он знает, как правильно это делать? Побитовую копию не предлагать, это практически **всегда** неправильно.

Comment: @VladD есть идея при создании клона перебирать основную коллекцию, создавать new Vm(){ //состояние объектов } и добавлять их в новую коллекцию.

Comment: Ну да, так по идее и надо. Но лучше пусть клонированием занимается сам объект, это его компетенция. Написал это в ответе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите глубокое клонирование, ваш класс `Vm` должен уметь правильно склонироваться. Например, он должен предоставлять функцию `Clone`:

```
class Vm
{
    ...
    public Vm Clone()
    {
        return new Vm(...) { ... };
    }
}
```

В этом случае клонировать получается просто:

```
_observable = new ObservableCollection<Vm>(obs.Select(vm => vm.Clone()));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Еще можно ICloneable реализовать.

Comment: @Lightness: Можно и `ICloneable`, но там `Clone` [возвращает `object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), что достаточно неудобно.

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!